# Multiparameter function for location comparison not performing, but Syntax analysis shows no issues | JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Need assistance with fixing this function in my JS script. I have made plenty of Python scripts and used Bing AI chat to help me convert a code I made for comparing location information into a JS script. The script has to be missing like one piece of the syntax, but I am not sure what argument is needed to help the function perform as intended. Do I need to close the URL at the end in quotes? Not sure how similar "navigate" is to "launch" in Python. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
function fun1() {
    let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
    let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
    let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
    let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;
    if (!TextInput1.Text) {
        let varCurrentLocation = Location.Longitude;
    };

    if (TextInput1.Text === "") {
        var varCurrentLocation = Location.Longitude + " " + Location.Latitude;
    } else {
        var varCurrentLocation = TextInput1.Text;
    };

    if (
        Location.Longitude < varGeofenceLon1 && Location.Longitude > varGeofenceLon2 &&
        Location.Latitude < varGeofenceLat1 && Location.Latitude > varGeofenceLat2
    ) {
        navigate("there is a URL I use here");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `TextInput1`? Also, what exactly is the problem? What goes wrong? Are errors reported in the browser console? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Also you're mixing up how declarations work. Your `varCurrentLocation` should be declared with `let` at the top with the other variables. When it's set, you just need simple assignments, not new declarations.

Comment: Well also, it's not clear what the point of `varCurrentLocation` is even; it never gets used after being assigned a value.

Comment: To answer these in order, "TextInput1" is a form field that acts as a text input. The submit button for the form created references the function "fun1" when clicked.

Comment: OK, well the value of an `<input>` element is accessed via the ".value" property, not ".Text".

Comment: However, when clicked it does not navigate, which means the function is not completing.

"varCurrentLocation" is meant to be set as the text from "TextInput1" if the field contains context. If the field is blank then the variable is set as the user's current location.

varCurrentLocation will be used later in another code referenced on the JS file, but could also be used to replace the Location.Longitue and Location.Latitude.

Comment: @Pointy That is a good first step to know, I write a lot in Python and PowerFX and use the MS visual studio for coding. I find it weird that it didn't give me any screen errors when I wrote that into the html.

Comment: If the variable is declared in that function, then no it will not be used elsewhere in the JS file; it is local to that function and other code can't see it. The "location" object is that, not "Location", and it is not about geographic location. (Perhaps your "Location" comes from somewhere else, but that also is not included in the code you posted.)

Comment: Well JavaScript is a different programming language; any object might have any property.

Comment: Again, keep your browser console open. That's where errors are reported.

Comment: So I actually just tested it again after double checking the URL parameters, I also noticed that I defined varCurrentLocation twice for no reason lol. The URL was not enclosed properly so the navigate function was not being recognized since everything after the broken part of the URL botched the code. Also worth noting that the "Location.Latitude" and "Location.Longitude" are case sensitive. As an FYI those objects are pulled via a bing maps api call since you had asked earlier and I didn't answer.

Comment: Corrected Code

function fun1() {
  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;

if (TextInput1.Text === "") {
    var varCurrentLocation = Location.Longitude + " " + Location.Latitude;
} else {
    var varCurrentLocation = TextInput1.Text;
};

if (
  Location.Longitude < varGeofenceLon1 &&
  Location.Longitude > varGeofenceLon2 &&
  Location.Latitude < varGeofenceLat1 &&
  Location.Latitude > varGeofenceLat2
) {
  navigate("");
}}

Comment: Another note: You were correct I didn't need to define it since the API call is already working to pull the coordinates for comparison with the geofence. The best code here is function fun1() {
  let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
  let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
  let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
  let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386; if (
  Location.Longitude < varGeofenceLon1 &&
  Location.Longitude > varGeofenceLon2 &&
  Location.Latitude < varGeofenceLat1 &&
  Location.Latitude > varGeofenceLat2
) {
  navigate("");
}}

Answer (score 0):

1. The variable "varCurrentLocation" is not needed at all for the function to perform the data comparison. As the location being compared is pulled by an API call.
2. The URL needs to be formatted within parenthesis to launch (I was missing the close apparently).
3. The correct code looks like this:

```
    function fun1() {
      let varGeofenceLon1 = 30.384219;
      let varGeofenceLon2 = 30.248352;
      let varGeofenceLat1 = -97.718391;
      let varGeofenceLat2 = -97.769386;
    if (
      Location.Longitude < varGeofenceLon1 &&
      Location.Longitude > varGeofenceLon2 &&
      Location.Latitude < varGeofenceLat1 &&
      Location.Latitude > varGeofenceLat2
    ) {
      navigate("URL Goes Here");
    }}
```